# How do I hook my monitor to this computer?

Tags: display, vga, adapter

I'm trying to hook my monitor to this computer. Mine is VGA, I'm assuming it goes where the blue port is? I see no other place for a monitor to plug in...Is there an adapter I need? sorry, but yes, I am clueless. =)

carrie

[[image: vga plug]]

[[image: back of computer]]

Comment: In your picture there is no type or correct number of pins for the plug in your hand. Take the cable in your hand and a picture of the back of your computer and also the back of the monitor to your local computer store and ask them for the correct cable

Comment: thanks john...i know it doesn't match, just wondering if there is an adapter that would work? something i can buy on amazon? I have no computer store nearby (small town problems)

Comment: It may be more than a simple cable difference. You need someone to look at the monitor and then know what the graphics card is inside the computer. Perhaps a friend can help.

Comment: ok, thank you for your input! =) much appreciated...!

Answer (score 1):

The image of the back of the computer omits the section which would normally contain the monitor connection. It's possible that the expected SVGA connector is covered by a plastic cap, which would indicate that the computer was configured for an on-board graphics adapter card.

If you plan to take a photo to a computer store, include the lower part that is missing. Alternatively, post another photo with that section visible. Also post a photo that shows what are called "slot covers" where one would typically find a graphics adapter card.

If you are bold enough, remove the side cover from the computer and take a photo of the mainboard. This will allow the viewers to advise regarding an existing graphics adapter card and/or the type needed to provide a location for connecting your existing monitor.

My bets are on a configuration which once included a card, has a capped SVGA port.